# Access 2010 VBA for SQL Server 2017 connection string

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I inherited an access 2010 database (ADP) and I am trying to understand the connection string.  If someone could help break it down for me that would very helpful.  Not understanding what it all means. I want to eventually upgrade to a linked tables access 2013 database.

I researched all over the internet to no avail. Will be also migrating to a new server that is using sql server 2017.  My biggest challenge is understanding what i+16 and i2-i+16 is.

This is what I have:

```
Sub CheckDBName()
Dim m As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer

On Error Resume Next
m = CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString
i = InStr(m, "Initial Catalog=")
i2 = InStr(m, ";Data Provider=")
m = Mid(CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString, (i + 16), 
(i2 - (i + 16)))
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? This is just basic string manipulation to break apart pieces of the connection string.

Comment: Yeah, what @SeanLange said.  First the code finds where those two key terns occur in the connection string, then it does simple string parsing to extract the text between them.  Notice that "Initial Catalog=" is 16 characters long - that's where "I + 16" comes from.  Frankly, I'm not a fan of that approach, since the elements of a connection string aren't guaranteed to be in the order that the code you posted demands.

Comment: I am pretty new to this arena, please excuse my misunderstanding and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian explained in the comments, this code extracts the text between the "Initial Catalog=" and the ";Data Provider=" strings, in other words the database name. He correctly pointed out that this could break if the elements of the connection string are in a different order. To avoid that, I would access the Properties collection of the Connection,  like this:

```
m = CurrentProject.Connection.Properties("Initial Catalog")
```